# How-to check that powershell script is running in Azure

Tags: azure, powershell

I have a powershell script, that I am developing on local PC and deploying onto Azure.  The script uses credentials, that are handled differently on PC and in Azure.  I therefore need to reliably check whether the script is running on the PC or on Azure.

I cannot find any command, that tells me the answer. I hope you can help.

Comment: What does “on azure” mean for you? Inside an Azure VM? Azure function? ...?

Comment: I mean ... running in a runbooks

Comment: have you checked `$host` or `$PSVersionTable`? i suspect that the azure host would be different from the local host ... [*grin*]

Comment: I have tried both $host ans $psversiontable, but none of these displayed any information, that can tell, whether the PS script is running in azure (that is, in an azure runbook).  Still looking for a solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is old but if the goal is to just be able to run the script locally for development then this should work.

```
if ($env:computername -ne "<EnterYourComputerNameHere>") {
    # Script is running in Azure
    # use Azure Automation credentials
} else {
    # Script is running locally
    # us Local credential process
}
enter code here

#do the remainder of your work
```

I checked in Azure for specific environment variables.  Looks like this would be more appropriate in this case:

```
if ($env:AUTOMATION_ASSET_ACCOUNTID) {
    "Running in Azure Automation"
} else {
    "Running outside of Azure Automation"
}
```

I hope that helps a little bit more.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  This solved my problem !!

I had hoped for a more versatile solution, but without generality, one may work with less :-)

Thanks alot.

Comment: `$env:AUTOMATION_ASSET_ACCOUNTID` doesn't exist on Azure.

Comment: I've just been informed that Azure is migrating the Automation runtime from something called the "SQLPAL" sandbox to Azure Containerized Instances, and the `AUTOMATION_ASSET_ACCOUNTID` is going away. This has been causing my runbooks to fail for a week. Finally got a straight answer from Azure Support.

Answer (score -2):

Welcome to StackOverflow! You can use multiple ways:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-execution#viewing-job-status-from-the-azure-portal
2. Send logs to output-stream:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-output-and-messages#output-stream

3. Send logs to Azure Monitor:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-manage-send-joblogs-log-analytics

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, but these suggestions does not solve the problem.  I need a wey to write an if-statement, where the condition is true, only when the script is run in an azure runbook.  Initially, I was under the assumption that the cmd [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Platform would give the answer, but it returns ‘Win32NT’ both on the pc and in the azure runbook.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. Here is a way you can use to figure out if it is a VM or local - https://stackoverflow.com/a/28161983/10571855

Comment: Thanks again, but this does not work either.  dmidecode reports, that /dev/mem does not exist.  My guess is, that the example relies on a Linux (judged from the use of the grep command).

Comment: To check if it is a windows VM check if a process named WindowsAzureGuestAgent.exe is running or not -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/agent-windows#manual-detection. To check if a process is running on windows you can use `tasklist` -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162291/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-via-a-batch-script